# list of python (nested) dicts to one nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a list of dicts that looks something like this:

```
[{u'control_set': {u'no_prediction': 'v1'}}
{u'control_set': {u'wrong': 'v2'}}
{u'prediction_set': {u'right': 'v4'}}
{u'prediction_set': {u'wrong': 'v3'}}]
```

I want to convert it into one deep nested dict:

```
{u'control_set' : {u'no_prediction': 'v1',u'wrong': 'v2'}
 u'prediction_set' : {u'wrong' : 'v3', u'right' : 'v4'}}
```

seen a couple of solutions around, but all seem to assume a constant deepness of the product and I'm looking for something general

Thanks

Comment: You should show what you have tried and where you got stuck.  SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
orig = [{u'control_set': {u'no_prediction': 'v1'}},
        {u'control_set': {u'wrong': 'v2'}},
        {u'prediction_set': {u'right': 'v4'}},
        {u'prediction_set': {u'wrong': 'v3'}}]

new = {}
for row in orig:
    for set_name, inner in row.items():
        temp = new.get(set_name, {})
        temp.update(inner)
        new[set_name] = temp
print new
```

Which should yield

```
{'prediction_set': {'wrong': 'v3', 'right': 'v4'},
 'control_set': {'no_prediction': 'v1', 'wrong': 'v2'}}
```

Now if there are multiple rights, wrongs or no_predictions in the original data you need some logic to handle that. Maybe with a list? May I ask where you intend to use this code?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try to use a Tree of Dict?
You can put the dict, inside "data".

```
tree = Tree()
tree.create_node("x", "x")  # root node
tree.create_node("y", "Y", parent="x",data=dict)
```

Look here ( at the end of the page):[treeLib](https://github.com/caesar0301/treelib/blob/master/docs/source/examples.rst)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.